# check state of another functional component

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks, react-props, use-state

i am new to react, i want to call the state of an outside function, for example :

```
 export default function Child() {          
  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
}
```

---

```
    export default function Parent() {     
          if(Child.succeeded){
             // do the following
          }
    }
```

i know that props are used for const objects only, and i don't want to merge both functions in a signle one to keep things organised, i would like to ****check** for child's state** to do the next step, or to **callback** the parent function with the new state to **notify** it. is there any way to do it ? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: There are a number of approaches to achieve this (callback, context, etc). To use the callback method make the child take a prop called `onSuccess` that is a function that has a single boolean parameter. On the child if the function exists call it whenever you change success. The parent can then utilise this callback to get notified of whenever `succeeded` has been changed.

Comment: man, that was cleannn! thanks a lot it worked like magic!!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is that you can use the **useRef**, which is very handy in some cases.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";


export default function Child({nameRef}) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    nameRef.current = name;    
  }, [name]);
  return (
   <>
      <input nameRef={nameRef} type="text" onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)} />
   </>
  );
}

import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import Child from './Child';

function App() {
  let [name, setName] = useState("Nate");

  let nameRef = useRef();

  const submitButton = () => {
    console.log(nameRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{name}</p>

      <div>
        <Child nameRef={nameRef} />
        <button type="button" onClick={submitButton}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```